# Normalizer/Centralizer theorem

Tags: group-theory

This is exercise 3.2.24 from Scott, *Group Theory*.

If $H$ is a finite maximal abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a normal abelian subgroup of $G$, then $K$ is finite.

The hint is to use Normalizer/Centralizer theorem.

Comment: Hint: The fact that $H$ is MAXIMAL Abelian is crucial.

Comment: Note that $Aut(H)$ is a subgroup of $S_{|H|}$.

Comment: I like giving hints too! What can you say about abelian normal subgroups of $C_G(H)$?

Comment: @SteveD: $C_{G}(H)=G$?

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Where are you getting that from?

Comment: Further Hint: What about $C_K(H)$ and $K/C_K(H)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $H$ is finite, $Aut(H)$ is finite. By the Normalizer/Centralizer theorem, $\frac{N_{G}(H)}{C_{G}(H) }= \frac{G}{C_{G}(H)} \ $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(H)$ and so is finite. Now we note that if $M \ \trianglelefteq \ G \ $, $M$ is abelian and $M \leq C_{G}(H) \ $, then $HM$ is abelian and normal in $G$, but $H$ is maximal abelian normal so $HM\leq H \ $ and then $M\leq H \ $. Note that 
$K \cap C_{G}(H) \ $ is abelian because $K$ is abelian and $K \cap C_{G}(H) \trianglelefteq G  \ $ because $K \trianglelefteq G \ $ and $C_{G}(H) \trianglelefteq G$. Then $K \cap C_{G}(H) \subseteq H \ $ and so $K \cap C_{G}(H) \ $ is finite because $H$ is finite. $\frac{KC_{G}(H)}{C_{G}(H)} \simeq \frac{K}{K \cap C_{G}(H)}  \ $ is a subgroup of $\frac{G}{C_{G}(H)} \ $ and so is finite. Then $|K| = |\frac{K}{K \cap C_{G}(H)}| \cdot |K \cap C_{G}(H)| \ $ is finite.

Comment: @stefHi-I've been following this with interest. I am a beginner, so maybe I could pose a question. If H is maximal normal and abelian, then K, being normal and abelian is either in H or is equal to G. In the first case you're done. So is there any way to say that G is finite - along the lines that G can't be isomorphic to the integers since all subgroups are of the form nZ. Or if G were to be infinite, K could not equal G, because a normal abelian group (i.e. the integers) wouldn't have a finite normal abelian subgroup. Or maybe some other way to force either G to be finite or K to be in H.

Comment: @Andrew you can conclude that K is H or G only if $H \leq K \ $

Comment: @StefThanks. Maybe you would please help me with what "maximal" means. I was thinking no normal abelian subgroups between H and G. Which would force K to be in H or equal to G. Regards, Andrew

Comment: @Andrew If K is normal and abelian you can say that HK is normal but not that HK is abelian

Comment: @StefThanks again.