# Group of an order 385

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $385$. Prove that $Z(G)$, the center of $G$, contains an element of order $7$.

I used the Sylow theorem and realized that there are one Sylow $11$-subgroup, which is normal in $G$, and also one Sylow $7$-subgroup, which is normal as well.

I tried to solve it with the commutator of $G$ and concluded that $G'$ is trivial. Does it make sense? Anyway I will be glad for a clue.

Answer (score 13):

Every group of order 385 contains a central Sylow 7-subgroup and a normal Sylow 11-subgroup. Indeed, note that $385 = 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$. Now Sylow’s Theorem forces $n_7 = n_{11} = 1$, so that $G$ has a unique, hence normal Sylow $7$- and a normal Sylow $11$-subgroup. Let $P_7$ denote the (unique) Sylow $7$-subgroup.

We have $N_G(P_7) = G$. Hence we obtain $G/C_G(P_7) \leq \mathsf{Aut}(P_7)$. Moreover, $|\mathsf{Aut}(P_7)| = 6 = 2 \cdot 3$. Thus $|G/C_G(P_7)| = 1$, so that $G/C_G(P_7) = 1$, hence $C_G(P_7) = G$. Thus $P_7 \leq Z(G)$.

Comment: can you please explain how you got this $G/C_G(P_7)≤(P_7). Moreover, |(P_7)|=6=2⋅3. Thus |G/C_G(P_7)|=1$

Comment: By the normalizer-centralizer theorem we obtain $G/C_G(P_7) \leq \mathsf{Aut}(P_7)$, e.g., see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93662/normalizer-centralizer-theorem).

Comment: Note that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/p)\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\times}$ has order $p-1$.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Every_Sylow_subgroup_intersects_the_center_nontrivially_or_is_contained_in_a_centralizer), a 7-Sylow subgroup of $G$ intersects the center of $G$ nontrivially.

Comment: I know that this is old, but I'm having trouble proving that the Sylow 7-subgroup is not contained in the centralizer of a noncentral element. Could you elaborate on this a little bit?