# Let $G$ be a group of order $385$. Prove that $G$ is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I want to prove

***Let $G$ be a group of order $385$. Prove that $G$ is not simple.***

Can you check my attempt please ?

*Since a simple group $G$ is a group in which the only normal subgroups are the trivial ones, namely $\{e_G\}$ and $\{G\}$, we want to show here that the given group $G$ has a normal subgroup, we want to show that there is a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, $n_p=1$ for some prime $p$.*

*Let $ord(G)=385=5^1 \times7^1 \times11^1$.*

*Since $5 \nmid7,5 \nmid11$ and $7 \nmid11$, $G$ has subgroups of order $5,7$ and $11$.*

*So $G$ has $3$ $p$-Sylow-subgroups with $p=5,7,11$:*

***P** a Sylow $5$-subgroup of order $5$*

***Q** a Sylow $7$-subgroup of order $7$*

***R** a Sylow $11$-subgroup of order $11$*

*With Sylow it follows that $n_{7}|55$ which means*

*$n_7 \in \{1,5,11,55\}$ and $n_{7}\equiv 1 \mod 7$* but

*for $5$ and $11$ $n_{7}\not\equiv 1 \mod 7$ which results in $n_{7}\in \{1\}$*

*Again with Sylow it follows that $n_{11}|35$ which means*

*$n_{11} \in \{1,5,7,35\}$ and $n_{11}\equiv 1 \mod 11$* but

*for $5,7$ and $11$ $n_{11}\not\equiv 1 \mod 11$ which results in $n_{11}\in \{1\}$*

Since we've found an unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, $n_p=1$ for some prime $p$ this group must be a normal subgroup and tehrefore $G$ is not simple.

Comment: Wait.  We should have $n_7\equiv 1\pmod 7$, and $n_{11}\equiv 1\pmod {11}$.

Comment: Which seems to imply $n_7=n_{11}=1$, since $n_7\mid{55}$ and $n_{11}\mid 35$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416772/group-of-an-order-385?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea,  but I think you made a mistake in applying Sylow's theorems.

For instance,  since $n_7\equiv 1\pmod 7$, and since $n_7\mid 55$, we have right away that $n_7=1$.

So your counting argument won't be necessary.

Comment: For similar reasons we have $n_{11}=1$.

Comment: Thank you, I made some Edit. One more question - would it be enough to just find out that here $n_7 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ or do I need to show it for $n_{11}$ also ?

Comment: You just need one non-trivial normal subgroup to show that the group isn't simple.

Comment: @ACME Thank you really much !